# Abort Merge conflict resolve midway

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I merged branch A into branch B and got merge conflict in some files say 5.
I resolved merge conflict in 2 files but now i want to abort the merge and want the 2 files for which i resolved the conflicts to go back as they were initially before resolving the conflicts. How do I do that.

Comment: Simply discard your changes; it sounds like you haven't committed anything yet, and the previous commit just before the merge will be at the point where there are the conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

If your merge was not completed, you can do a [`git merge --abort`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---abort).

Check the content of those files: if they are not fully reverted to their initial content, do a `git checkout -- myfile`: that will reset their content to the current index.

Answer (score 1):

To abort the current conflict resolution process, and try to reconstruct the pre-merge state.

you can use `git merge --abort` (assuming your Git version is 1.7.4 or greater).

If you're on an older Git (but newer than version 1.6.1) you can use
`git reset --merge` .